# How to redirect http to specific URL using htaccess in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for assistance with the redirection rules.

### I have url www.example.com.au and I want the following redirections

### https://www.example.com.au =>https://www.example.com.au

### http://www.example.com.au =>https://www.example.com.au/page-2

I found the following .htaccess rules but its not working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www^example\.com.au [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%. 
{HTTP_HOST}%www^example.com.au/page-2 [302 L]
```

can anyone please help me the correct rule.

I will be using the above rule for a WordPress site so do i need to paste the above rules at the bottom so that it doesn't overruled by other rewrite rule?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first redirection it is impossible, it will create an infinite loop. You can not redirect an url on itself.

And for the second one ( http://www.example.com.au =>  https://www.example.com.au/page-2 ) you can do something like that

`Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com.au/page-2`

Pay attention to 301, it indicates that the redirection is permanent, I do not know if it is your goal.

But if your goals was to redirect http to https you can do something like that (put on the top of your .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or use a plugin like [Really Simple SSL](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/)

Then you can define your rules to redirect one page to another before the rule above, like this:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page /new-page
```